# Oracle JDBC sql statement where is null does not return any data

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a java project where I need to fetch a count of the number of rows not having a date set (the date is null for these rows in the Oracle table).

The project is in Java 6 using Oracle jdbc 6. (ojdbc6.jar).

```
Statement statement = null;
String query = " select count(*) thesum from jobview where starteddate is null";

statement = con.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
if(resultSet.next()) {
   workCount = new Integer(resultSet.getInt("thesum"));
}
```

Now, the problem is that workCount is always 0.

If I run the same query in SQLDeveloper it returns a result with the number of rows with starteddate as expected (meaning not 0).

What am I missing here or are there some know bugs with the oracle driver or my version of java (build 1.6.0_29) which is a project restriction...

Comment: Do you connect to the same database ?

Comment: Yes I've checked and I connect to the same database with the same credentials

Comment: Where do you read the workCount variable, and why do you put the result in a new Integer()? What happens if you remove the where part of the query?

Comment: have you inspect resultSet variable before to apply next function?

Comment: the code is in a method that I call to get the number of rows that need I need to look at. So workCount is a return from that method.

Comment: If you try to access resultSet before calling the next() method you get a stack trace "java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called"

Comment: Removing the where clause gives me a large number which corresponds to the number of rows in that table. So that gives me the expected result, but the where statement part seems to break it when calling through the jdbc driver. The issue seems to be specifically related to the "is null" part.

Comment: Could you try resultSet.getInt(1) instead?

Comment: I've tried using resultSet.getInt(1) and it gives 0 as well.

Comment: What results do you get in SQL Developer if you change "is null" to "= null"? Is it possible JDBC is converting the "is null" to "= null"?

Comment: I've tried running with "=null" in SQL Developer and that indeed gives me zero result rows. So it does seem like the JDBC is converting it. How to avoid this and end up with a runnable query though..?

Answer (score 0):

Our development environment was set up using **Ubuntu 12.04 Lts** through the **VMware Player free** versions **5.0.2-1031769** and **6.0.1-1379776**. Both were exhibiting this error.

We swapped the **VMware Player free** with **VMware Workstation** licenced edition and it now works as it should. So this issue seems to have to do with a combination of the virtualization software, operating system and java (jdbc driver). I hope others having the same problem find this post so it saves them a lot of grief and time trying to debug this issue.